# MVC Entity Framework Edit View for a Model with a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Project model and a Skill model,

the Project has a one to many relationship to skills

I am having an issue figuring out how to do the edit actionmethod for the Project,

When the project object is instantiated by mvc,  the skill collection is null, in the view I display checkboxes and need to add and remove from this collection

I figure I need to load the Project from the database and then map the modified fields and then save, is this the right way to go about it? is there a better way to do this than doing it manually?

Thanks in advance.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (project.Skills == null)
            { 
                project.Skills = new List<Skill>();
            }
            foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key.Contains("Skill_"))
                {
                    if (Request.Params[key].Contains('t'))
                    {
                        var skillId = Convert.ToInt32(key.Split('_')[1]);
                        if (!project.Skills.Any(s => s.ID == skillId))
                        {
                            project.Skills.Add(db.Skills.Single(s => s.ID == skillId));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            List<Skill> skillsToRemove = new List<Skill>();
            foreach (var skill in project.Skills)
            {
                if (!Request.Params["Skill_" + skill.ID.ToString()].Contains('t'))
                {
                    skillsToRemove.Add(skill);
                }
            }
            foreach (var skill in skillsToRemove)
            {
                project.Skills.Remove(skill);
            }
            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.Skills = db.Skills.ToList();
        return View(project);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating ViewModel for your project and use it to populate skills and project on your view.

example

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
   public Project Project {get; set;}
   public List<Skills> Skills { get; set;}
}
```

then in you controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id){
   var model = new ProjectViewModel
   {
      Project = YourContext.Projects.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ProjectId == id),
      Skills = YourContext.Skills.ToList()
   };
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProjectViewModel model){
    if (ModelState.IsValid){

       //now you can use skills from the ViewModel
       foreach(Skill s in model.Skills){
          //you  should now have skill value.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I figured like that
My foreign key Product ID and you need to put it on bind include list
Controller;

```
 public ActionResult EditTextProperty([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductID,Name,Description,Value,CreateDate,ModifyDate,IsHaveNectar")] PVM_TextProperty TextProperty)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(TextProperty).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(TextProperty);
        }
```

and also bring it from view by using hidden property like that
View;

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductID)
```

Thanks